# Attribute Error Installing with pip

Tags: python, macos, pip

This is a head stumper so I am posting this question AFTER having examined and read all of the prior posts on this issue.

Running OSX 10.9 Python 2.7 no virtualenv

```
pip install awssh

Downloading/unpacking awssh

  Downloading awssh-0.1.tar.gz
Cleaning up...

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pip/basecommand.py", 

line 122, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pip/commands/install.py", 

line 274, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder, force_root_egg_info=self.bundle, bundle=self.bundle)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", 

line 1215, in prepare_files
    req_to_install.run_egg_info()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", 

line 288, in run_egg_info
    logger.notify('Running setup.py (path:%s) egg_info for package %s' % (self.setup_py, self.name))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pip-1.5.2-py2.7.egg/pip/req.py", 

line 265, in setup_py
    import setuptools
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>

    from setuptools.extension import Extension
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/extension.py", line 8, in <module>

 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 21, in <module>
    packaging = pkg_resources.packaging

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'packaging'
```

Comment: Whoops, just realized I had old `apt-get` versions of `setuptools` and `pip` installed on my laptop.  I removed those, and the error persisted with `setuptools` 14.3.  In fact, the error is raised upon import of `setuptools`.

Comment: same with `setuptools` 16.0.

Answer (score 22):

This error is caused by the presence of an outdated version of `pkg_resources`.  In order to get rid of the error, do the following:

1. Start a python session, import `pkg_resources`, and view the file from which it is loaded:

   ```
   In [1]: import pkg_resources

   In [2]: pkg_resources.__file__
   Out[2]: '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.pyc'
   ```
2. Remove this file (and the associated `*.py` file):

   ```
   $ sudo rm /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pkg_resources.py*
   ```
3. That's it!  Re-run the installation; it should complete without any errors:

   ```
   $ sudo pip install awssh
   ```

### Warning

If you're on a Debian based Linux system, this file might have been installed via the `python-pkg-resources` package. Therefore updating or reinstalling this package will reinstate the stale module! Also be aware that you're messing with a file which is supposed to be controlled by `apt`.

Comment: Solved it. Good stuff.

Comment: @dbliss when I import `pkg_resources` it gives me the following path: `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-5.7-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.pyc` but when I try to remove it I receive: `rm: cannot remove ‘/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-5.7-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.pyc’: Not a directory`. Any turnaround for this ?

Comment: @Dex looks to me like you're using the `rm` command incorrectly.  maybe with the `-r` argument?  what is the exact command you're executing?

Comment: @dbliss I'm getting the same because `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-5.7-py2.7.egg` is a file, not a folder, that looks like this: http://cl.ly/e9qM

Comment: @Dex I fixed the issue on my machine by `sudo rm`-ing `setuptools-5.7-py2.7.egg`, and then running `pip install setuptools`.  Running the commands above now gives me `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.pyc` and the `AttributeError` is gone.  _Note: I don't really know anything about Python so this may have been dangerous or unnecessary, but it worked for me._

Comment: I was ok after a pip uninstall of setuptools and re-installing it