# DigitalOcean module not loaded or installed properly

Tags: python, digital-ocean

I'm trying to use the digitalocean python module found [here](https://github.com/koalalorenzo/python-digitalocean).

I installed it with: `sudo pip install -U python-digitalocean`

In python shell, I get:

```
>>> import digitalocean
>>> manager = digitalocean.Manager(token="secretspecialuniquesnowflake")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Manager'
```

And:

```
>>> dir(digitalocean)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__']
```

I'm quite new to python so I'm not sure what's gone wrong. Can someone help please?

Comment: Have you restarted the shell environment?

Comment: Did you try this one? http://stackoverflow.com/a/30310206/2011147

Comment: @felipsmartins I tested in a new terminal session.

Comment: @Selcuk It didn't help. I just installed numpy and it worked. Still the same issue with the DO module though.