# ImportError: No module named extern

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip, setuptools, importerror

I'm getting this error when trying to install any package with pip. I have two pip instances, one with Python 2.7 and other with Python 3.

```
    Could not import setuptools which is required to install from a source distribution.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 375, in setup_py
    import setuptools  # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    from setuptools.extern.six.moves import filterfalse, map
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/extern/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from pkg_resources.extern import VendorImporter
ImportError: No module named extern
```

Even when I try to install the 'extern' module I get this error. Also when installing with Python itself, like `python setup.py install`.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: do you use virtualenv?

Comment: Yes, I use virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper.

Comment: Can you mention which OS are you using ?

Comment: I'm using an ubuntu-based distro.

Comment: I ran into this problem recently, and it might be worth making a bug report to virtualenv. I ended up downgrading to 12.0.7. This introduced a new error that I was able to resolve here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28967785/attribute-error-installing-with-pip/30310206

Comment: Reinstalling setuptools didn't work me on OSX 10.11.7. Can you please help me. My error says no module named extern as well.

Comment: I'm experiencing this exact same issue on Windows.  pip for 2.7 and for 3, each in venv.  Cannot find `pkg_resources.extern`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
sudo apt-get purge python-pkg-resources
sudo apt-get -f install
```

here actually packages are removed and 
        purged (any configuration files are deleted too).

-f : Attempt to correct a system with broken dependencies in place.

`sudo pip install packagename`

[#sourcehere](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529217/not-able-to-fix-the-error-unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-pack)

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing
additional context regarding _why_ and/or _how_ this code
answers the question would significantly improve its
long-term value.  Please [edit] your answer to add some
explanation.

Comment: Though I don't really quite understand what's going on in here, helped me two times already.

Answer (score 4):

Do this it will work

```
sudo pip install -U setuptools
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that just gets me an error from pip about `'module' object has no attribute 'PROTOCOL_SSLv3'`

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old thread, but I just wanted to contribute since I ran into this issue and this thread kept coming up in the results.

*Note: This was on MacOS 10.12. My shell is zsh and I already have brew installed*

First I ran each of these commands

```
brew install python
brew install python3
```

This will either install it or you'll receive an "already installed" message as I did.

Next, run the following command

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

And last:

```
sudo python get-pip.py
```

Final note: for my install to work, I ended up having to run the command with pip3

```
sudo pip3 install nameofinstallhere
```

Comment: This fixed the problem for me on macOS 10.13.4 when nothing else did. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure whether it is installation issue or packege but it seems like you will not be able to import any package of them, if you have installed python perfectly then

try this commands

step 1 :

```
$which pip
/usr/local/bin/pip
```

step 2 :

```
/usr/local/bin/pip install django
```

or any of your package name.
I am considering ubuntu(OS)

Comment: This solved https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1064, but thank you for answering.

Comment: If you're going to be using the `pip` that is returned by `which` (i.e., first on the path), you don't need to use the absolute path to it in step 2. The solution is simply `pip install django`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following command; it has worked for me:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-setuptools
```