# Import setuptools fails

Tags: python, macos, pip, setuptools, importerror

I am trying to install some packages using `pip` on OSX 10.11.6 and it is always failing.

Whenever I try to install some package I am getting the error about missing extern. I have tried to fix the extern thing by [ImportError: No module named extern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446765/importerror-no-module-named-extern) but without success.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 6, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-intel/egg/setuptools/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.11-intel/egg/setuptools/extern/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named extern
```

I have tried deleting all my setuptools file and in `/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/` and reinstalling but it doesn't work still.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named extern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35446765/importerror-no-module-named-extern)

Comment: @dbliss The solution of reinstalling doesn't work for me that's why I asked it. I have mentioned that the past solution of reinstalling the setuptool doesn't work on my OSX.

Comment: when an answer to an existing question does not help you, the solution is not to repost the same question.  post a comment under the answer that does not help.

Comment: Well, the solutions on the earlier question had for Ubuntu. I had explicitly refered to the original question while posting my question and how it didn't solve my problem. I hope you atleast read the question before commenting or flagging duplicate in future. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue of the problem was different version of distribute was troubling my installation.

I went to my python package directory

```
 /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages
```

and fixed the problem by running the following command. I reverted my installation back to distribute_0.6.14 via

```
python distribute_setup.py
```

This fixed my setuptools and now I am able to install and run things normally.